# name description caption don't appear in the wall post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

using Facebook Javascript SDK (since FBml doesn't work anymore), posting to a wall using my facebook app does not display name, description and caption at all. I tried adding a link and display, removed description as well, none seems to fix the issue.

Any help or note on this is helpful.

```
var description = $(this).parent().parent().children('.description').html();
var name = $(this).parent().parent().children('.name').html();

FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    attachment: 
    {
      name: name,
      caption: 'Test App',
      description: description,
      link: appLink,
      href: appLink                       
    },
    action_links: 
    [
      { text: 'Test App', href: 'appLink' }
    ]
  },
  function(response) 
  {
    if (response && response.post_id) 
    {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } 
    else 
    {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually a facebook bug. I've reported it to Facebook but haven't got any feedback since December 2011 after they've confirmed it a bug and assigned medium priority. Cheers.